# How to resolve error related to httpClientConfigCallback?

Tags: java, authentication, elasticsearch

setHttpClientConfigCallback()  is showing error in my code even after importing all related libraries. I am working with Maven and the Eclipse is indicating that (The method setHttpClientConfigCallback(( httpClientBuilder) -> {}) is undefined for the type RestClient.Builder).
I am a noob to the elasticsearch. Thank you in advance.

final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider=new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user,password));

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host,port,protocol))
        .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder->httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error when I try to connect it for the first time. Try overriding the method instead of using lambda expression. Once the error resolves, change it back to lambda expression. Hope that helps!

Sample code for your reference.

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback;

 RestClientBuilder builder= RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder arg0) {
                        // Your code
                        return null;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Edited the answer for better understanding!